# Difficulty reloading changed shell function

Tags: shell, zsh, dot-files

I have a function defined in a file `~/.shell/functions.sh` that is loaded by `.zshrc` with a line:

```
source ~/.shell/functions.sh
```

However, when I try to update the function after altering it by doing `source ~/.zshrc`, it doesn't seem to load the new version of the function.

I.e. the current function in my saved buffer looks like:

```
pparselogs () {
    while read data; do
        echo "$data" | jq -Rr '. as $line | try fromjson catch $line'
    done
}
```

However, if I do use zsh's `functions` cmd and do `functions pparselogs`, I get:

```
pparselogs () {
    while read data
    do
        jq -Rr '. as $line | try fromjson catch $line' < "$data"
    done
}
```

Notice that the `jq` command line is different in the two versions -- and the first one is the one that I want.

Why would doing a `source` not update the function? How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it possible that you also have an `alias` defined for `pparselogs`? Or that you have an alias whose body contains `pparselogs` and the name of that alias is also used to define a function? What's the output of `alias | grep pparselogs`?

Comment: Does it work if you source `~/.shell/functions.sh` directly?

Comment: BTW, the syntax to read a line in zsh is `IFS= read -r data`, not `read data`, and the syntax to output text as one line is `printf '%s\n' $data` or `print -r -- $data` or `echo -E - $data`, not `echo $data`.